# The 3 key components of a robot are controller, servo, and reducer. Can someone give us an "official" explanation of what they do respectively?

Tags: microcontroller, rcservo

I've googled a lot but wasn't able to find official definitions of these 3 parts. Maybe the explanations of [servo](http://www.seattlerobotics.org/guide/servos.html) and [controller](http://open-robotics.com/what-is-the-definition-of-a-robot-controller/) are good enough, but I'm still trying to look for a more "official" one.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't agree that those are the three key conponents of a robot.    Maybe I'd agree if you were talking about the drive for a single robot axis of motion.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* snakeninny, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: As @SteveO states, your question is built around the assumption that the three key components of a robot are a controller, servo, and reducer. I would be more inclined to agree with NBCKLY below (sense, think, act) - where are you getting your definition of a robot from? What are you calling a "reducer"?

Comment: As a 1 month robotics noob, I think I may have some misunderstandings. @NBCKLY 's answer is pretty much what I was expecting, and I'll take a look at the books he mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is premised on a misunderstanding of what a robot is composed of, but you are close.

A robot is an agent that is capable of *sensing*, *thinking*, and *acting*. The sense-think-act (or sense-plan-act) paradigm has historical significance in behaviour based robotics, and you can read about it in Ronald Arkin's book *Behavior-Based Robotics.*

The two of the three components that you mention in your question fall neatly into the categories of sensing, thinking, and acting. **Sensing** components, as the name suggests, gather data from sensors about the environment (internal or external). Common sensors include accelerometers, gyroscopes, cameras, radar, lidar, etc.. **Thinking** is implemented in a computing environment, small robots will use a micro-controller to facilitate this. On the computer, algorithms, controllers (the control theory type), artificial intelligence (and so on) process the sensor data as input and determine a desired output objective. **Acting** components, which include servo motors as you mentioned, are responsible for interacting with, or actuating in, the environment.

With this brief description, hopefully you better understand what a robot is at an abstract level, which should inform you as to what the physical components are for at a high-level. I will again point you to Arkin's book. The *Springer Handbook of Robotics* is another good resource that will certainly answer your questions.